# Trying to convert RHEL6 init script to systemd

Tags: bash, shell-script, systemd, sysvinit

I currently have an init script on a RHEL 6.x box that is used to start various license servers for an engineering group.

Each vendor has their own processes, env variables and other specifics to start/stop license servers, so over the years I have created a START, STOP, STAT script for each application that map the vendor specific stuff into a standard for our site.  This allowed me to create the following generic init script that I could soft link to any application via a link in `/etc/sysconfig/init.d`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   START/STOP/STAT license servers
#
# chkconfig: 345 95 05
# description: Startup/Shutdown license servers

#####################################
#   Who/When/Where
#
WHO=`who am i`
WHEN=`date`
WHERE=`hostname | cut -f1 -d "."`

#####################################
#   Figure out how we were called
#
APPNAME=`basename $0 | cut -f2 -d "_"` ; export APPNAME
SERVICELOG="/license/$APPNAME/logs/service.log" ; export SERVICELOG

echo "/etc/init.d/ License Script was ran at: $WHEN app was: $APPNAME command was: $1" >> $SERVICELOG

#################################################
#   Time to call App Specific Executable
#
case "$1" in
      start) su - licadmin /license/$APPNAME/scripts/START
             echo "$APPNAME Daemon Started $WHEN by $WHO on $WHERE" >> $SERVICELOG
              ;;
           stop)
              su - licadmin /license/$APPNAME/scripts/STOP
              echo "$APPNAME Daemon Stopped $WHEN by $WHO on $WHERE" >> $SERVICELOG
              ;;
         status)
              su - licadmin /license/$APPNAME/scripts/STAT
              ;;
 reload|restart)
              $0 stop
              $0 start
              echo "$APPNAME Daemon Restarted $WHEN by $WHO on $WHERE" >> $SERVICELOG
              ;;
              *)
              echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|reload|restart}"
              exit 1
              ;;
esac
exit 0
##########################################################################
#EOF(lic_init)
```

I've looked into the documentation for systemd and I am really struggling on how to preserve my standard since a lot of what I do "seems" to be native to systemd (start/stop/stat) and I don't want to just have a new systemd service that just calls my Bash script.

Any ideas on how to handle my conversion?

Comment: bolting a sysv script into systemd is not unknown, see for example `/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirt-guests.service` on Centos 7 (`libvirt-client` RPM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break it down into smaller parts:

- WHO/WHEN/WHERE are handled by systemd's journal. You can query the journal for any unit, e.g. `journalctl -u $APPNAME.service`, so these are not necessary here and could be removed.
- Likewise, $SERVICELOG can be replaced by the systemd journal. No more concerns about managing your own log rotation.
- Custom "status" commands are supported directly by systemd. Instead, you can use `systemctl status` for a standardized status output. If you really want a custom status command, that would be implemented as a separate systemd `service`.
- What's left is that you have multiple services that you want to stop and start the same way, by the same user. systemd [template units](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/) are designed to solve that problem. You can create a single template unit, and then for each app, you can create an instance of that that template: `systemctl start licensedapps@someapp`